# How to send php variable from view(html) to controller

Tags: php, html, codeigniter, codeigniter-2

This is my html code. I want to pass "`$category_edit->c_name`" value to my `Update()` controller. I am getting "`$category_edit`" variable from another controller.

I am using CodeIgniter framework.

```
<form method="post" action="<?php echo base_url('admin/category/update');?>">
 <label>Parent Category: </label></br>
 <select name="parent_id">
 <?php
    echo '<option value="' .$category_edit->id .'">';
    echo $category_edit->p_name;
    echo '</option>';
 ?>
 </select>
 <label>Category</label>
 <input type="text" name="<?php echo $category_edit->c_name; ?>" id="category_name" value="<?php echo $category_edit->c_name; ?>">
 <button>Update</button>
</form>
```

This is my `update()` controller. 
I am getting Error:

1. Undefined variable: category_edit
2. Trying to get property of non-object

   ```
   public function update(){
      $this->load->model('category_model');
      echo $category_edit->c_name;
   }
   ```

Comment: $category_edit this is not gloabal variable.

Comment: check my answer brother

Comment: add your controller code. **Error is `Undefined variable: category_edit`**. It means `category_edit` Array is empty.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please kindly check this reference code:

```
public function update_view()
{
    $this->load->model('category_model');

    $data['category_edit'] = $this->category_model->get_category_values(); // return array
    $data['extra_variable'] = 'lorem ipsum';

    $this->load->view('category/update_view', $data);
}
```

at your  `category/update_view.php` :

```
<form method="post" action="<?php echo base_url('admin/category/update');?>">
 <label>Parent Category: </label></br>
 <select name="parent_id">
 <?php
    echo '<option value="' .$category_edit['id'] .'">';
    echo $category_edit['p_name'];
    echo '</option>';
 ?>
 </select>
 <label>Category</label>
 <input type="text" name="<?php echo $category_edit['c_name']; ?>" id="category_name" value="<?php echo $category_edit['c_name']; ?>">
 <button>Update</button>
</form>
```

**EDIT:**

Please refer: http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/views.html#adding-dynamic-data-to-the-view

Comment: **Error is `Undefined variable: category_edit`**. It means `category_edit` Array is empty. Your answer is wrong. It won't print any data to view.

Comment: dude, its your work now that It must not return empty array as you are doing database work. "OR" make validation for it. "I can show you path, Not complete program". I am absolutely right, this is the same copy from my project.

Comment: <?php print_r($category_edit); exit; ?> in your view. see whats printing.

Answer (score 2):

Make some changes in HTML(See below code)

```
<input type="text" name="category_name" id="category_name" value="<?php echo $category_edit->c_name; ?>">

public function update()
{
$this->load->model('category_model');
echo $this->input->post('category_name');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to add name of field static not any variable.
so try to add like this

```
<input type="text" name="category_name" id="category_name" value="<?php echo $category_edit->c_name; ?>">
```

and on controller you can get value of it like

```
$this->input->post('category_name');
```

Comment: **Error is `Undefined variable: category_edit`**. It means `category_edit` Array is empty. Your answer is wrong. It won't print any data to view.

Comment: this one is for controller, for view you have to get it.

Comment: user has asked from view to controller